# Migration from Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.0.M3 to M4

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

In Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.0.M3 I used `UpdateQuery.builder().withUpdateRequest()` while building UpdateRequest directly. So I could set `retryOnConflict()` parameter.

After moving to M4 I can't set it anymore because there is no `withUpdateRequest()` method in the `UpdateQuery` and the `UpdateRequst` is being built internally. `UpdateQuery.builder` doesn't provide an option to set `retryOnConflict()`.

My question is what is the right way to migrate my code so that I will have full control over `UpdateRequst`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

wait for 4.0.0.RC1. I just merged the code to expose all the update query parameters on the `UpdateQuery.builder`

Comment: Thanks @P.J.Meisch. What is the 4.0.0.RC1 expected date?

Comment: please check https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Neumann

Comment: could you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64771780/updating-elasticsearch-entities-with-bulk